# New Element in MooTools by UID

Tags: javascript, mootools

Is it possible to instantiate an element on Mootools based on the automatic UID that mootools create?

EDIT: To give more info on what is going. I'm using https://github.com/browserstate/history.js to make a history within an ajax page. When I add a DOM element to it (which does not have an id), at some point it passes through a JSON.toString methods and what I have of the element now is just the uid.

I need to recreate the element based on this UID, how could I go about doing that? Do I need to first add it to the global storage to retrieve later? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in view of edited question:

sorry, I fail to understand what you are doing.

you have an element. at some point the element is turned into an object that gets serialised (all of it? prototypes etc?). you then take that data and convert to an object again but want to preserve the uid? why?

I don't understand how the uid matters much here...

Using global browser storage also serialises to string so that won't help much. Are we talking survival of page loads here or just attach/detach/overwrite elements? If the latter, this can work with some tweaking.

```
(function() {
    var Storage = {};

    Element.implement({
        saveElement: function() {
            var uid = document.id(this).uid;

            Storage[uid] = this;
            return this;
        }
    });

    this.restoreElement = function(uid) {
        return Storage[uid] || null;
    }
})();

var foo = document.id("foo"), uid = foo.uid;
console.log(uid);

foo.saveElement().addEvent("mouseenter", function() { alert("hi"); } );
document.id("container").set("html", "");

setTimeout(function() {
    var newElement = restoreElement(uid);
    if (newElement)
        newElement.inject(document.body);
    console.log(newElement.uid);
}, 2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/7mwmu/1/

this will allow you to remove an element and restore it later.

keep in mind that i do `container.set("html", "");` which is not a great practice.

if you do `.empty()`, it will GC the foo and it will wipe it's storage so the event won't survive. same for `foo.destroy()` - you can 'visually' restore the element but nothing linked to it will work (events or fx).

you can get around that by using event delegation, however.

also, you may want to store parent node etc so you can put it back to its previous place.

Comment: First thanks for the answer Dimitar. But I think it doesn't address exactly what I need and that is my fault for not explaining things correctly. I will edit it to explain a little better of what is going on.

Comment: When the Element is serialized the only thing that is left is the UID and an empty construct. I need to get it back from the DOM. I ended up stored on the window store and retrieving later. But thanks for all the great explanations.